# Base64 image from IOS to php service

Tags: php, ios, service, web, escaping

If I send the image to php server, only in base64, the percentage of transmission is almost zero due to special characters (eg + * /).
If I send so it is successfully sent, but the image appears without data on the server. Somebody help how to solve this, side php?

```
string = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];  // iOS 7+

NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                                  NULL,
                                                                                  (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                  NULL,
                                                                                  CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" "),
                                                                                  kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

NSString *urlString2= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"mylink.com/xyz"];

```
NSString *jsonString2= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"{\"id_sala\":\"%@\",\"base\":\"%@\",\"tipo\":\"IOS\"}",iddsala,encodedString];
 NSLog(@"%@",encodedString);

NSData* responseData2 = nil;
NSURL *url2=[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
responseData2 = [NSMutableData data] ;
NSMutableURLRequest *request2=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
NSString *bodydata2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonString2];

[request2 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *req2=[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodydata2 UTF8String] length:[bodydata2 length]];
[request2 setHTTPBody:req2];
NSURLResponse* response2;
NSError* error2 = nil;
responseData2 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request2     returningResponse:&response2 error:&error2];
responseString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. You should be use `NSJSONSerialization` to build the JSON. Doing it manually with `stringWithFormat` only introduces potential problems.
2. Do not percent escape the base64 string. `NSJSONSerialization` will automatically ensure the JSON is properly formatted.
3. Unrelated to the original question, but it's best practice to set `Content-Type` header to reflect the particulars of the request body.
4. Also unrelated, but you really should be using asynchronous requests. You should never issue synchronous network requests from the main queue.

Thus:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mylink.com/xyz"]; // don't forget http; also all of those `stringWithFormat` references building urlString2 was entirely unnecessary

NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];  // iOS 7+

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"id_sala" : iddsala,
                             @"base"    : base64String,
                             @"tipo"    : @"IOS"};
NSError *error;
NSData *httpBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(httpBody, @"dataWithJSONObject error: %@", error);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:httpBody];

NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!data || error) {
        NSLog(@"sendAsynchronousRequest error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    // use the `data` result here; e.g. if JSON response

    NSError *parseError;
    id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
    if (responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", responseObject);
    } else {
        // some problem parsing JSON; it's often useful to keep at the body of the response to diagnose problem
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"responseString = %@", responseString);
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved!!! Perfect!! This variable is to forget.

Answer (score 0):

As a  solution to your problem please try decoding the base64 encoded image data using urldecode (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) in your php script.

And then write image data to file using file_put_contents (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Also please try executing sample code snippet

E.g

```
      $img_data=urldecode(base64_decode($img_data));
      file_put_contents($filename,$img_data);
```

Comment: If this answer solves the problem, then it's apparent that OP is using a request that doesn't need percent escaping at all. It's silly to manually percent-escape a string only to manually un-escape it on the other end.